# Continue an SSIS task when one of many servers is down

Tags: sql-server, ssis

The purpose of my SSIS package is to grab data from one centralized server and multicast that data to several servers.

I have one central server and 5 destinations.

I truncate each destination server's tables, then send each table to all destinations using a multicast. Each data flow object updates one table on each server.

I need to stress there are no for-loops. This data flow is relatively linear.

These destination servers have unreliable internet connections, so I need to plan for if at least one destination is offline.

I've tried to disable error messages, as seen here

- http://agilebi.com/jwelch/2008/06/29/continuing-a-loop-after-an-error/

I've tried setting the max error count to a high number.

However every time I try to execute, the package stops entirely and complains that one of the connections is broken (I broke it on purpose to test). How can I force the package to continue, despite at least one bad connection?

Thanks

Comment: Disabling the error messages is only akin to inviting more trouble down the line. I would not recommend you do that.

Answer (score 0):

Put each server in 1 data flow task. When you connect one data flow to the other, instead of using the Success/Failure precedence constraint, set it to completion. A word on performance: This will slow down your processing as you wont be able to multicast anymore. But this will also make sure that if one of them fails, the others can still continue and do their job.

If you would still like to use the multicast method, I would suggest writing a script in the script component. But that will be tangled mess as well once you encounter failure and need to debug it.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than iterate through a loop of dynamically generated connections (as many solutions on google suggested), I slimmed the SSIS task down to only modify one table at a time, so no more multicasting.

The key was to modify the connection string at SQL server manager's task level.

I set up a task for each connection under the Jobs menu on the server. Each task has a connection string. I modified this connection string under "data sources" after setting the package to the SSIS package. Every step started with the same SSIS package connection string as a default (since I was creating steps using the same package over and over), but if I changed the server address, everything worked out fine. To be clear, I just modified "Data source =server.address.here;" and "Initial catalog=TableToModifyOnThatSpecificServer;". All other info in each connection string was the same.

Fun fact, the "Password=#passwordGoesHere;" portion of the connection string will disappear. It's still there though, so don't freak out.

I know this doesn't fix the problem at an SSIS level, but I wish I'd known this a few days ago. Good luck to anyone reading up on this looking for answers!